# Android: Share file between two application without using external storage

Tags: android, file-sharing, android-internal-storage

I am trying to share database file between two Application, suppose i have App A and App B. App A creates the database for me and its used by App A and App B as well. But When i uninstall my App A my database is also deleted but i want to keep that database if my App B is installed and if both are removed it should remove database from storage. I want to keep my database always on internal storage.

Comment: not possible databases are application specific..!!

Answer (score 1):

@R.Pradhan please try Content provider thru data send. App A to App B Data send using database.

Comment: Content Provider, you mean?

Comment: @KenRatanachaiS. Please chk this link and read. "http://www.compiletimeerror.com/2013/12/content-provider-in-android.html"

Comment: @KenRatanachaiS. Content provider thru data send to recevied. App A to App B using Database

Comment: You misspell to "container providers". Just that i wanted to point out.

Comment: @mujjuraja I tried using ContentProvider but when I delete my App A it deletes database also

Answer (score 0):

@R.Pradhan.. Yes you can share a single database between two application but for that there is one condition.

If you want use data between application (provided they are issued by the same publisher) you will need to specify a shared user id in the AndroidManifest.xml of both application.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:sharedUserId="my.app" ... >
```

the shared user id need to be a string with at least one dot separator.

The rest is easy, and you don't need to mess around with the database path. Just use the same DBAdapter in both apps. In the app that hosts the database, call the DBAdapter with the native context.

```
DBadapter hostDBAdapter = new DbAdapter(getApplicationContext());
performerDBadapter.open();
```

In the second app, access the database with the context of the database hosting app.
First, define the shared context:

```
Context sharedContext = null;
    try {
        sharedContext = this.createPackageContext("replace.with.host.package.name", Context.CONTEXT_INCLUDE_CODE);
        if (sharedContext == null) {
            return;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        String error = e.getMessage(); 
        return;
        }
```

Then open the DBAdapter with the shared context:

```
DbAdapter sharedDBadapter = new PerformerDbAdapter(sharedContext);
sharedDBadapter.open();
```

As a final note, if your database exists previous to setting the shared user id in the manifest, you will need to uninstall/reinstall the apps on a physical device, lest you will lock yourself out of your database (sqlite error 14). The emulator, on the other hand, might prove to be more forgiving. Bottom line, if your apps are published on the Android market, setting a shared user id in an afterthought will not work.

Hope this helps.